# Sitecore 5.3 (Intranet) GetUser and performance

Tags: performance, active-directory, sitecore

I am experiencing performance issues on a Sitecore Intranet Portal installation that relate to the GetUser method of the domain (Extranet). The extranet domain contains roughly about 800 users and calling *Sitecore.Context.Domain.GetUser(userName)* takes about 12 seconds at very least. Using a direct login model to authenticate the user against the Active Directory (LDAP) takes almost 60 seconds just to get the user logged in.

Any tips on performance tuning users in Sitecore 5.3? Is there a point when the number of users become to many for Sitecore to be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I know LDAP can be very slow, if you don't assign what kind of connection it should use (ssl, signing etc). Then it'll try to negotiate with the AD which kind of connection it should use and that can be very slow.

We had an issue with a customer that had this problem and the login went from 20+ seconds to about 1 second.

So if you're using your own LDAP module or similiar that could be the case.

If you are using Sitecore LDAP module, I dunno if you can set it up.

Since I didn't create that fix and am not very proficient in AD I'm not suer what to do, but maybe the following code can help you:

```
var connection = new LdapConnection(d);
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
NetworkCredential nw = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;
connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
connection.Bind(nw)
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks old to answer. but AD Ldap module is using the same binding you mentioned here.